# secureTextEntry is not hashing my password React Native

Tags: react-native, password-encryption

When I type my pin password inside my app it shows the digits without hashing them. Is secureTextEntry is the right property for password encryption or is there something else?

SetPinScreen.js:

```
return (
        <View style={{width: 250, height: 170, backgroundColor: Colors.trans, alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20, textAlign: 'center', color: this.props.color}}>{this.props.title}</Text>    
            <TextInput 
                ref={"pinTextField"}
                maxLength={4}
                clearTextOnFocus={true}
                style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto', width: 160, height: 100, borderBottomWidth: this.props.showUnderline === true?1:0, borderBottomColor: this.props.color, fontSize: 60, textAlign: 'center', color: this.props.color}}
                value={this.state.inputCode} 
                clearTextOnFocus={true}
                autoFocus={true}
                secureTextEntry={true}
                keyboardType={"phone-pad"}
                onBlur={this.onKeepKeyboardVisible}
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoCapitalize={"sentences"}
                caretHidden={true}
                underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                onChangeText={(text) => this.handleTextChange(text)}/>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 16, textAlign: 'center', color: Colors.red}}>{this.state.errorMsg}</Text>   
        </View>
    );
```

Comment: what version of react-native are you using?

Comment: it's a bug: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10678

Comment: The version is 0.55.4

Comment: @riwu what do you mean by bug?General bug?

Comment: RN bug. You have to wait for the fix, remove `keyboardType="phone-pad"`, or implement your own text censoring.

Comment: @riwu thanks it worked when I changed it to keyboardType="numeric"

Answer (score 2):

it is not working if you use  `keyboardType={"phone-pad"}` 
remove keyboardType and it will works fine

Answer (score 1):

secureTextEntry - If true, the text input hides the text entered so that sensitive text like passwords stay secure. The default value is false. It does not work with multiline={true}.